# What jquery validate methods are in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking at asp.net mvc 3.0 and how it uses unobtrusive javascript through the jquery.validate library.

I am having trouble on finding what validation methods are supported. I only can find that mvc 3.0 can used the jquery.validate remote.

Does this new way use still data annotations and is limited by the couple they have or does this use something completely different?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-Side validation is enabled by default in ASP.NET MVC 3. It uses unobtrusive javascript implementation based on the [jquery.validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) which is also included by default. Unobtrusiveness is achieved thanks to the new HTML5 data-* attributes which are automatically emitted by the standard HTML Helpers based on the model metadata. Client-side validation works out of the box for all standard attributes in the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) namespace including the [`[Remote]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.aspx) attribute ([see example here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/04/ASPNETMVC3RemoteValidationTutorial.aspx)). It will not work out-of-the-box with custom defined attributes deriving from [ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx) or with [IValidatableObject interface](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).

The following section in web.config controls client side validation:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Comment: So if I want to use Max,Min,credit card,compare and etc from jquery validate I have to write my own dataAnnotation?

Comment: @chobo2, for Min and Max you could use the [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx) attribute. For credit card you need custom code or try the `RegularExpression` attribute but I am not sure whether you could validate a credit card number with regex. You might also checkout the [following blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) which goes into more details.

Comment: I don't get the "Bridging HTML and jQuery Validate: Adapters" part. It seems like if I want to make my own ones to use jquery validate I have to write some adapters but it does not go into how to make them. It also looks like there are some already made but it does not seem to show you how to use them.

Comment: This might help: http://samipoimala.com/it/2010/11/29/unobtrusive-client-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/comment-page-1/#comment-3685

Comment: @chobo2, you may checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747184/perform-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute/4747466#4747466

Comment: @The Flower Guy - So the validation adapters that are already supported how would I hook them up with ones? Like if you look at Darin link it seems like there are alot of adapters setup. How do I use them?