# Passing Value to Jquery validation at runtime in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have jquery function as validationtype its working fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.validator.addMethod("mytest", function (value, element, param) {
    var emailPattern = /^[0-9]+$/;
    return emailPattern.test(value);
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("mytest");
```

but my req is i need to pass regex at runtime to this function

how to achieve this, i tried like...

```
ValidationType = "mytest";
```

ValidationParameters.Add("newregex", strrew);

its reflecting in html like....

input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-mytest="The ContactPersonName field is Required." data-val-mytest-newregex="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{50,100}$/"
 id="Desc" name="Desc" type="text" value=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784943/asp-net-mvc-3-client-side-validation-with-parameters/4784986#4784986) useful.

Comment: var myPattern = /^(\+?((([0-9]+(\.)?)|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+))([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?))$/; this is working
var myPattern = param1; this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what your looking for, but for ease you could use the remote validation attribute.