# Negating specific characters in regex

Tags: c#, regex

How can I block white space in textbox entries?

I tried this but it is not working:

```
  [RegularExpression(@"/^\s/", ErrorMessage = "white space is not allowed in username")]
  public string UserName { get; set; }
```

'^' negation should not allow white space in text but it does not allow me to enter any text in field. Any help?

Comment: Do you need to use regex for this? Try to find a space and if you find one, prevent from getting further.

Comment: i am working with Data Annotations, so i need to stick with regex

Comment: @"^[A-Za-z0-9\[\]/!$%^&*()\-_+{};:'£@#.?]*$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\S` (which is negation of `\s` = non-whitespace character):

```
@"^\S+$"
```

If empty string is allowed, replace `+` with `*`:

```
@"^\S*$"
```

Comment: There's no `/` delimiter in .net regex

Comment: @Anirudh, Thank you for comment. I fixed it according to your comment.

Comment: @Arun, it's likely the `^` and `$` terminators. Remove them and it will probably yield the results you're looking for.

Comment: i tried @"/\S+/" but still not working? i am keep getting validation for non-white space string

Answer (score 3):

`^` works as "negation" only inside character classes, e.g. `[^ ]` means any character except space. When used outside of `[]`, `^` means "at the beginnign of the string. So your original RE says "A space at the start of the string" - almost exactly the opposite to what you want.

I am not the familiar with specifics of C# REs, but from the rest of the answers, the RE you want is probably `^\S+$`: 1 or more non-space characters between beginning and end of the string.

Comment: i am not familiar with Regex, my requirement is to not allow white space in string, all other characters and symbols are allowed

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Character Classes".

Answer (score 2):

Just saw the comment you said "you need to work with DataAnnotation", here is the way to do it without Regex

```
public class WhiteSpaceCheckerAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var strValue = value as string;
        return strValue != null && !strValue.Contains(" ");
    }
}
```

**usage**

```
[WhiteSpaceChecker(ErrorMessage = "white space is not allowed in username")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

This doesn't cover client side validation which you can easily implement. Following link should help you with that concept [Client-side custom data annotation validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987490/client-side-custom-data-annotation-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without RegEx. By adding this code in the KeyPress Event of your textbox.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = e.KeyChar == ' ';
}
```