# Regex for capitalizing first letter in a tag, alt=", etc

Tags: regex

I've found regular expressions that capitalize the first letter in a sentence. But does anyone know a regex that capitalizes the first letter inside a tag, including URL and image attributes (e.g. title="antelope" or alt="antelope").

I used another regex to change all my image paths to lower case, and it zapped a bunch of my tags as well (alt, title, h2, etc.). So now I'd like to get a head start fixing them by capitalizing the first letters.

I'm working on a Mac, using Dreamweaver and TextWrangler as my text editors.

Before...

```
alt="antelope" title="antelope" <h2>antelope
```

After...

```
alt="Antelope" title="Antelope" <h2>Antelope
```

Comment: Give a before and after example.

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

```
(="\w|>\w)
```

### Replace Regex

```
\U$1\E
```

***Description:** This will work for your example, depending on the regex engine you are using.*

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AvwDdVECWRLBi6cE)

Comment: @aliteralmind `\E` stops the uppercasing.  Since the only thing in the group will be symbols `\U` doesn't do anything to them...`\u` requires me to break my regex into many many more groups.

Comment: Hmmmm...None of the above regexes are working for me in Dreamweaver or TextWrangler. Maybe I just need a third text editor. ;) I think Notepad uses a different regex engine. (I'm on a Mac, though.) I'll check out the StackOverflow Regex FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

*This replaces the value in parameters in a url. NOT in html, as I now see that is what you mean. Oh well.*

- Find what: `(\?|\&)([a-z_]+=)([a-z])([^&]+)`
- Replace (all) with: `$1$2\u$3$4`

Free spaced:

```
(\?|\&)
```

[Capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127) 1: Either the [literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078) question mark or ampersand.

```
([a-z_]+=)
```

Capture group 2: One or more of any lowercase letter or underscore, followed by the equals sign.

```
([a-z])
```

Capture group 3: The first letter in the value of the url parameter. Note this does not even notice parameters whose values don't start with a letter.

```
([^&]+)
```

Capture group four: Every other character in the value. Or more specifically, one or more of any character as long as it's *not* an ampersand. This is a [negative character class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20802463).

The \u in the replace-with is an option in TextWrangler (and in TextPad, which is what I use...so TextWrangler might also use the [Boost regex engine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html)) replacement that uppercases the immediately-following character. I'm not sure if this would work if capture groups 3 and 4 were merged.

[Try it](http://regex101.com/r/aF4wJ3) (although it doesn't have the `\u` option.)

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. There's a *lot* of helpful information in it, including a list of online regex testers (in the bottom section), so you can try things out yourself. All the links in this answer come from the FAQ.