# REGEX in java with replaceall and on multiple line

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a string :

```
0000000000<table blalba>blaalb<tr>gfdg<td>kgdfkg</td></tr>fkkkkk</table>5555
```

I want to replace the text between `table` and `/table` with : "", to delete this text to display only 00000000005555.

When it is on one line, it works:

```
chaineHtml = chaineHtml.replaceFirst("[^<title>](.*)[</title>$", "");
```

But the same with `table` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("<table.+/table>", "");
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Comment: thanks a lot it 's VERY GOOD !!!!it's great it works perfectly, thank you also for your reply as fast!

Comment: @The Guy with The Hat it means replace text which starts with "<table" and ends with "/table>" with "" (remove actually)

Answer (score 3):

This regex should work:

```
html = html.replaceAll("(?is)<table.+?/table>", "");
```

Where `(?is)` will make it match across **multiple lines** and ignore case.

But I suggest you should not manipulate HTML using regex as it can be error prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [^<table>]
```

I don't think that means what you think it means.

It is not "a string not equal to <table>". Rather, it means "a *character* not equal to < or t or a or b or l or e or >". "[^...]" is called a [negative character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801127/disable-white-space-in-text/20802463#20802463).

Change your regex to

```
 (.*?)<table>.*?</table>(.*?)
```

replace it with

```
$1$2
```

and it will give you the result you wish.

---

Please consider bookmarking [The Stack Overflow Regular Expeession FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) for future reference. The bottom section contains a list of online regex testers where you can try things out yourself. You may also want to check out the sections named "Character Classes" and, as mentioned by @anubhava: "General Information > Do not use regex to parse HTML"

Comment: Problem is that the sample regex don't go along with the sample input.

Comment: @BheshGurung: Meant "table". Fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("<table.*?table>", "");
```

**Explanation:**

```
Match the characters “<table” literally «<table»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the characters “table>” literally «table>»
```

Comment: One line answers are not good style. Please consider adding explanation, particularly so other readers will understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use regex if you are not familiar with its concepts!**

There is a simple plain java solution for your problem:

```
String begin = "<table";
String end = "</table>";
String s = "0000000001<table blalba>blaalb<tr>gfdg<td>kgdfkg</td></tr>fkkkkk</table>4555";
int tableIndex = s.indexOf(begin);
int tableEndIndex = s.indexOf(end, tableIndex);

while (tableIndex > -1) {
    s = s.substring(0, tableIndex) + s.substring(tableEndIndex + end.length());
    tableIndex = s.indexOf("<table");
    tableEndIndex = s.indexOf("</table>", tableIndex);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a brilliant solution I found somewhere:
Using the Regex

```
[\s\S]
```

to fit any character, including newlines because it fits any space or non-space characters. So in your case that would give:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<table[\\s\\S]+/table>", "");
```

the double backslashes are to escape the backslash.

Another possiblity is

```
(.|\n)
```

which is any character (except newline) or newline which gives:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<table(.|\n)+/table>", "");
```

For some reason, on my computer, in certain combinations, when I use `(.|\n)+` regex runs into a weird loop and goes into a stackoverflow:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at java.lang.Character.codePointAt(Character.java:4668)
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3693)

which doesn't happen when I use `[\s\S\]+` instead. I have no idea why though.