# Regex to capture characters not specified in pattern

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have a string `"this [is] not req!red"`

i am trying to create a regex which will pick "characters" not specified in the list

```
[-a-zA-Z.,-()=\s\+:?!*\;><0-9]
```

any suggestions how to achieve this?

Language is C#

Comment: Have you googled "regex not"? It's that simple. `[abc]` is "the character a, b or c". `[^abc]` is "any character that isn't a, b or c". `[^abc]+` is "any character that isn't a, b or c matched 1 to infinity times".

Comment: depends on your language, `^` at the beginning generally negates a character class and you can use captures to get them: `([^-a-zA-Z.,-()=\s+:?!*\;><0-9]).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: okay your regex changed to `[^-a-zA-Z.,\-()=\s\+:?!*\;><0-9]` selects only the square brackets so what is your problem?

Comment: Is your goal to end up with `this is not reqred`? To filter out all unwanted characters? Every letter is *unwanted*?

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: I am using C#, basically i want to replace all characters which don't match this particular pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is a [positive character class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553171) that matches each *legal* character specified in it:

```
[-a-zA-Z.,\-()=\s+:?!*\;><0-9]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/EBxTdCRLbaX2H7zx)

The characters you don't want aren't matched. To switch this around, to match only the characters you want, make it a [negative character class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20802463), by adding the `^` as its first character:

```
[^-a-zA-Z.,\-()=\s+:?!*\;><0-9]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cmn0P1tclXwL2hM-)

To capture the matches, put the entire regex into a [capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127):

```
([-a-zA-Z.,\-()=\s+:?!*\;><0-9])
```

or

```
([^-a-zA-Z.,\-()=\s+:?!*\;><0-9])
```

Then iterate through the matches in your language of choice. Each character is in capture group one.

I'm uncertain of your goal. More information would help us give you better answers.

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: I want to replace all those characters which are not in my Regex allowed list.

Comment: @UsmanMasood So you use the regex as `string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z.,\-()=\s+:?!*\;><0-9]", ".");` where "." is the replacement symbol.

Comment: I don't know C#, but as a generic regex replacement, it looks fine. Tell me what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this :

```
[^-a-zA-Z.,\-()=\s\+:?!*\;><0-9]
```

the `^` will negate every character present in the list .

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/vX0oQ7

so basically in your example, it will not select anything apart from the square brackets .

```
this [is] not req!red
     |  |
```