# How to remove possibly nested brackets using RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

> {{ some text {{ with nested text }} and again }} and some more text over here {{remove this too}}

I'd like to match the OUTERmost {{ }} brackets so that I'm left with:

> and some more text over here

This is what I have so far:

```
var text = Regex.Replace(content, "{{[^}}]*}}",string.Empty);
```

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE** Adding in some links that might be helpful:

{{.+?}}
http://www.regexr.com/3941i

{{.+}}
http://www.regexr.com/3941f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var text = Regex.Replace(content, "{{.+}}", string.Empty);
```

**EDIT ( Balanced Matching )**

```
string content = @"{{ some text {{ with nested text }} and again }} and some more text over here {{remove this too}}";

Regex re = new Regex(@" {{
    [^{}]*
    (
        (
            (?<Open>{{)
            [^{}]*
        )+
        (
            (?<Close-Open>}})
            [^{}]*
        )+
    )*
    (?(Open)(?!))
    }}", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

var text = re.Replace(content, string.Empty);
```

For more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx

Comment: That works but it seems to cheat a little - I'll change my example a little so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Is this a recursive regular expression? Yep. One booger of a regex. I didn't know C# could do that.

Comment: Under the `<Open>` line should it be this? `[^<>]*` or this? `[^{}]*`

Comment: great answer, but the "[^{}]*" is a little confusing since its not double {{}}. I am confused how would you solve for the example where the brackets {{ are replaced with non-identical characters 12 and }} are replaced with 34? Example string: 12TE12ST34ST34RING producing RING. Am I correct to try and use negative lookahead?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex

```
{{[^}}]*}}
```

Does not work ([try it](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%7b%5b%5e%7d%7d%5d*%7d%7d&i=%7b%7b+some+text+%7b%7b+with+nested+text+%7d%7d+and+again+%7d%7d+and+some+more+text+over+here)), because the `[^}}]` will not allow it to go past the first* close curly. If you want to capture "all close curlys except the last two", then you need

```
\{\{.*\}\}[ ]+
```

[Try it](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7b%5c%7b.*%5c%7d%5c%7d%5b+%5d%2b&i=%7b%7b+some+text+%7b%7b+with+nested+text+%7d%7d+and+again+%7d%7d+and+some+more+text+over+here)

I'm escaping the curlies to be safe. Although it works without them in regexstorm, they're special characters, and they should be escaped. I've also added the trailing space, to *only* capture the post-text, as you wish.

Note that this regex does not check that the curlies are balanced--it just blindly matches from the first two open curlies, to the last two. Regex is not suited to determining "balanced-ness".

(*The first, because the `[^}}]` is incorrect. The `[^...]` is a [negative character class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20802463)--it matches *any* ***one*** *character* that is not in the class (between the square brackets). So `[^}}]` is equivalent to `[^}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}]` is equivalent to `[^}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}]`.)

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: I updated my initial text.  I probably should have included the leading space for the resulting text since I don't want regex to look for that.  So are you suggesting this is not a good jog for regex?  what do you recommend?

Comment: I guess I should say *simple* regular expressions are not conducive to balancing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in one pass, this works in php, capture matched { } then trim off the outer brackets, repeat

```
(\{(?:[^\{\}]*+|(?0))*\})
```

other wise I would tokenize the string, break it into the {{, }} and text and process the results ( preg_match_all ) in php

```
(\{\{)|(\}\})|([^{}]+)
```

and process the results,

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{
            [1] =>  some text 
            [2] => {{
            [3] =>  with nested text 
            [4] => }}
            [5] =>  and again 
            [6] => }}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{
            [1] => 
            [2] => {{
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => }}
            [5] => 
            [6] => }}
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] =>  some text 
            [2] => 
            [3] =>  with nested text 
            [4] => 
            [5] =>  and again 
            [6] => 
        )

)
```

like
if( item == {{ ) ++nesting; etc. if you follow the logic.