# What is the balance matching regular expression for removing nested brackets composed of sets of ordered characters?

Tags: .net, regex, xml, cdata, parentheses

Following this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591578/1329812

I am trying to use balanced matching to replace all items within brackets but in the example the brackets are `"{{"` and `"}}"`. Whereas my brackets would be `"<![CDATA["` and `"]]>"`.

I am having trouble modifying the `[^{}]` section of the regular expression in the accepted answer to the previous question to use my version of brackets instead. I have tried to modify `[^{}]` to `(?!(<!\[CDATA\|\]\]>))`.

I have simplified the problem to use 12 as the open bracket and 34 as the close bracket. The following returns "STST" as expected.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex.Replace(
12T1212E343434STST12RING34',--input
'12(?!(12|34))*(((?<Open>12)(?!(12|34))*)+((?<Close-Open>34)(?!(12|34))*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))34',--pattern
''--replacement
);
```

However it does not work if i replace `12` with `<!\[CDATA\[" and 34 with "\]\]>`.

Finally, I would like to operate on the following CDATA Sample String:

```
"<![CDATA[t<![CDATA[e]]>]]>stst<![CDATA[ring]]>"
```

should return

```
"stst"
```

Comment: Is this a .NET compatible regex engine?

Comment: yes, its .NET I had missed a . between Regex and Replace.

Comment: Well, anyway, your regex is not working whatever you may think about it because `[^(12|34)]` matches a single char other than `(`, `1`, `2`, `|`, `3`, `4` and `)`. This - [`12(?>(?!12|34).|(?<o>)12|(?<-o>)34)*(?(o)(?!))34`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=12%28%3f%3e%28%3f!12%7c34%29.%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%2912%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%2934%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%2934&i=12T1212E343434STST12RING34) - is a correct one.

Comment: thank you, I have edited [^(12|34)] to (?!(12|34))

Comment: I updated my comment above. If you want a more specific answer, please provide an example with `CDATA`.

Comment: thank you, I have provided an sample input for the CDATA request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `12...34` matching regex is not right since the [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) used is "corrupt" (`(?!(12|34))*` is missing the consuming part, `.`).

You just need to remember about the parts of the regex like that: 1) the leading delimiter pattern, 2) the trailing delimiter pattern, 3) the part in between should match what is not both 1 and 2, 4) the [conditional construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#Conditional_Group) that checks if the "technical" group capture stack is empty.

So, the numeric regex can be fixed as

```
12(?>(?!12|34).|(?<o>)12|(?<-o>)34)*(?(o)(?!))34
```

([regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=12%28%3F%3E%28%3F!12%7C34%29.%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%2912%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%2934%29%2A%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%2934&i=12T1212E343434STST12RING34)) and the CDATA one will look like

```
<!\[CDATA\[(?>(?!<!\[CDATA\[|]]>).|(?<o>)<!\[CDATA\[|(?<-o>)]]>)*(?(o)(?!))]]>
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C!%5C%5BCDATA%5C%5B%28%3F%3E%28%3F!%3C!%5C%5BCDATA%5C%5B%7C%5D%5D%3E%29.%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%3C!%5C%5BCDATA%5C%5B%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5D%5D%3E%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5D%5D%3E&i=%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bt%3C!%5BCDATA%5Be%5D%5D%3E%5D%5D%3Estst%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bring%5D%5D%3E)

**NOTE**: If there can be newline symbols in the string input, use `RegexOptions.Singleline` option or the inline modifier version, `(?s)`, at the pattern start.

**Pattern details**:

- `12` - the leading delimiter pattern
- `(?>` - start of the atomic group that will match what is neither leading nor trailing patterns, and will keep track of those delimiting substrings:

  - `(?!12|34).|` - match any char (if `RegexOptions.Singleline` option is used, even including a newline) but a char that is a starting point of the `12` or `34` sequences
  - `(?<o>)12| - match`12` and increment the "o" group capture stack, or
  - `(?<-o>)34` - match `34` and decrement the "o" group capture stack
- `)*` - and repeat that (keep matching) zero or more occurrences of the patterns inside the atomic group
- `(?(o)(?!))` - the conditional construct that will check if the "o" group capture stack is empty. If it is not empty, backtracking will trigger, and balanced number of leading/trailing delimiters will be searched for.
- `34` - the trailing delimiter pattern.

Also, `[` in `<![CDATA[` must be escaped, as `[` is a special char outside the character class, and `]` in `]]>` do not have to be escaped, since outside a character class, `]` is not special for a .NET regex.

Comment: incredible! thank you for the further insight with the answer, the text does contain newlines so I am currently using the pattern "(?s)<!\[CDATA\[(?>(?!<!\[CDATA\[|]]>).|(?<o>)<!\[CDATA\[|(?<-o>)]]>)*(?(o)(?!))]]>"

Comment: @DannyRancher: Well, if there are no newlines, you may remove `(?s)`, the DOTALL/Singleline modifier that makes all `.` after it match LF symbols, too.

Comment: ok thanks, separately, I'm trying to simplify some larger strings into series of CDATA "brackets" what is the regex for identifying the CDATA brackets and only retaining them? `(?>(?!<!\[CDATA\[|\]\]>)`?

Comment: @DannyRancher That is something different. What is the sample test case? `<![CDATA[t<![CDATA[e]]>]]>stst<![CDATA[ring]]>` and the output is...

Comment: using the sample test case in your comment, i am trying to generate `<![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]>]]><![CDATA[]]>`.

Comment: @DannyRancher [Here is my attempt](https://ideone.com/ZPrIzA). It counts all the nested CDATAs in Group "a", and then the matched number of nested CDATAs are created inside the callback method passed to `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: thank you, although is this not overcomplicated? Some inputs don't seem to be working with the regex created in your answer. I am just trying to simplify them by removing everything except the "brackets" text to identify the issue. Your solutions are very interesting to learn from however.

Comment: @DannyRancher: I can only suggest writing a parser if you do not like that regex approach.

Comment: hmm i understand. i think instead i will modify the C# code to join the Match.Values in a StringBuilder before returning. thanks anyway

Comment: is there some reason the regex provided as an answer would be unable to identify brackets which differ by a large number of characters?

Comment: @DannyRancher No idea, I do not think so. Please share the string. http://pastebin.com can help.

Comment: ok so the problem is that there exists an invalid closing bracket within the data within the legitimate brackets. so imagine the input `())` and we are left with the second `)` instead of removing the whole input. is there any way to make the regular expression greedy to select the second closing bracket? Going back to the simple numeric example this is the same as input `12TE34ST34STRING` and returning `STRING`

Comment: @DannyRancher That is input error. I doubt you can add to the pattern and expect consistent behavior with the true and these "invalid" cases.