# What does [^a-z0-9] means in regex?

Tags: regex

Just wondering what does `[^a-z0-9]` mean in regex?

I looked around this site and only find `[a-z0-9]`, so what does the `^` symbol mean?

Comment: It means match a character that is not in range of `a-z` and `0-9`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801127/disable-white-space-in-text/20802463#20802463