# Custom data annotation validation on Client Site : $.validator.addMethod error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

From this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987572/2014745) I have  write my code from this blog [DevTrends](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for performing custom data annotation  validation. But in client site in  $.validator.addMethod( ) method getting the error in the bellowed image. Please help me to come out from this problem.

```
message  :"value is not defined"
stack  : "ReferenceError: value is not defined↵    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:61052/boatproduction/edit/2?pg=1&sz=10&st=id&dr=desc:71:13), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at http://localhost:61052/boatproduction/edit/2?pg=1&sz=10&st=id&dr=desc:1279:13↵    at http://localhost:61052/boatproduction/edit/2?pg=1&sz=10&st=id&dr=desc:1288:10"
```

[image]

My View model is like below

```
   public class BoatProductionModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; } 
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }        
    [DateComparison("StartDate")]
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }       
    public int? NumberOfEmployee { get; set; }        
}


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class DateComparison : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be the same as {1}.";
    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }

    public DateComparison(string otherProperty)
      : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherProperty))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("otherProperty");
        }

        OtherProperty = otherProperty;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, OtherProperty);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                          ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
                               .GetProperty(OtherProperty);

            var otherPropertyValue = otherProperty
                          .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (value.Equals(otherPropertyValue))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(
                  FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }
        return null;  //return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> 
GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "notequalto"
        };

        clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", OtherProperty);

        return new[] { clientValidationRule };
    }
}
```

Here is the code  I used in View :

**Razor Code :**

```
 @model  Data.AppModels.BoatProductionModel
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastUpdate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control pull-right", placeholder = "Last Update"    })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastUpdate)
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
(function ($) {
            $.validator.addMethod("notequalto", function (value, element, params) {
                if (!this.optional(element)) {
                    var otherProp = $('#' + params)
                    return (otherProp.val() != value);
                }
                return true;
            });
            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("notequalto", "otherproperty");

        }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Do not change you question based in the answer! I have rolled back you changes.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenMuecke I am editing because I have put that in my code but even not working, So, just I am testing what you say before commenting   bellow your answer mean while you came here :). I am coming just after testing and again asking you :)

Comment: The answer I gave is correct. I copied your code exactly as it was, got exactly that error, then modified the attribute to implement `IClientValidatable` and the error dissapears, the `data-val-` are rendered and the client side validation works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom attribute does not implement `IClientValidatable` (although your have included the `GetClientValidationRules()` method defined in that interface. As a result the `data-val-*` attributes associated with your attribute are not generated in the html and therefore `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` does not add the rules to `jquery.validate.js`

Change the signature of your validation attribute to

```
public sealed class DateComparison : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    ....
}
```

and the html for your input will now include the following attributes

```
data-val-notequalto="LastUpdate cannot be the same as StartDate." data-val-notequalto-otherproperty="StartDate"
```

that will be parsed by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Note also that you do not need to wrap the scripts in `(function ($) {`

Comment: Here is my inspected code of LastUpdate textbox : <input class="form-control pull-right valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field LastUpdate must be a date." data-val-notequalto="LastUpdate cannot be the same as StartDate." data-val-notequalto-otherproperty="StartDate" data-val-required="The LastUpdate field is required." id="LastUpdate" name="LastUpdate" placeholder="Last Update" type="text" value="12/15/2017">  but unfortunately my client side validation isn't even working

Comment: Then have you included the relevant scripts? - `jquery-{version}.js`, followed by `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (and they need to be before you scripts.

Comment: Even I have remove the (function($){ portion and put it in $(document).ready(function() {

$.validator.addMethod("notequalto", function (value, element, params) {
                if (!this.optional(element)) {
                    var otherProp = $('#' + params)
                    return (otherProp.val() != value);
                }
                return true;
            });
            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("notequalto", "otherproperty");

});

Comment: Do **not** use `(function($){ ` or `$(document).ready(function() { `.

Comment: yes.    
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

Comment: Then just add the script as you have (without the `(function($){`) after those 3 scripts (immediately before the closing `</body>` tag in your view

Comment: That's worked perfect, but I am disappointed , what was my problem.

Comment: The problem was that you did not implement `IClientValidatable`, therefore the `data-val-*` attributes were not generated

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke need another help. That is If I change the condition in isvalid method from equal to less than if (DateTime.Parse( value.ToString()) < DateTime.Parse(otherPropertyValue.ToString())) it again not working in client side. Is there an mistake or some thing

Comment: Oh, got it ! need to change in JavaScript Code