# Unobtrusive DateTime? Validation in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I upgraded an MVC3 solution to MVC4. After the migration, the validator is broken.

My input date, if i select German as language, is "20.03.2013". I get an validation error in MVC4, but not in MVC3. If i replace the format from "20.03.2013" to "20/03/2013" it works in MVC4, but not in MVC3 ;-)

I set the UI culture of the current thread to german. The output of the ResX values are in the correct language, <s>so i know there should be no error with the culture.</s>, only for the site itself. The error messages are in english, but the site is in german.

I assume this means the validator uses the wrong UI Culture.

Here is the code i use.

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_DepartureDate", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resx.Query))]
public DateTime? DepartureDate { get; set; }
```

I assume there is something wrong with the default model binder, as the rendered html looks good:

```
data-lang="de" data-mindate="3" data-val="true" data-val-required="Bitte geben Sie das gew&#252;nschte Reisedatum des Hinflugs ein." id="DepartureDate" name="DepartureDate" tabindex="3" type="text" value=""
```

I upgraded the Jscript to the sources that ship when you create a new Mvc application using the Visual Studio 2012 (SP1 is installed) templates. This had no impact.

I have a CultureModelBinder which reads the current culture out of the Session and sets the culture using a small helper function.

```
public static void UpdateThreadCulture(CultureInfo culture)
{
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;            
}
```

The culture model binder is the default binder.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CultureModelBinder();
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeModelBinder());
// and many, many more
```

Maybe something changed in the execution order with mvc4 resulting the problem?

Update: The project uses .NET Framework 4.5 as target.

Update 2:

I have a combo box where the user can select 16 different languages, each might have it's own specific formatting.

E.g. 
DE-de -> DD.MM.YYYY; 
en-en -> DD/MM/YYYY; 
en-us -> MM/DD/YYYY

I just got a hint about setting the current culture, here is the proof it should be correct as it is. This code is not hit when the validators fail, it looks like it happens on the client side.

```
   public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private LogService _log = new LogService();

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {            
            object result = null;
            ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (valueResult != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var stateHandler = new StateHandler(controllerContext.HttpContext.Session);                    
                    result = valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime?), stateHandler.Culture);                                       
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime?), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _log.Error("DateTimeModelBinder parse exception", ex);
                        _log.KeyValue("AttemptedValue", valueResult.AttemptedValue);                                           
                    }                    
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and for completeness my culture model binder:

```
  public class CultureModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {      
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            StateHandler stateHandler = new StateHandler(controllerContext.HttpContext.Session);
            Helper.UpdateThreadCulture(stateHandler.Culture);

            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }        
    }
```

Update: Maybe there is a correlation to this problem:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/705643/a-data-val-date-attribute-is-generated-for-time-fields-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Update:
Read the following article:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx

tried the following out:

Loaded the scripts in the following order:

```
/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
/Scripts/globalize.js
/Scripts/cultures/globalize.cultures.js
// and much more other scripts...
```

added the call. the output was correctly "DE".

```
        var currentLanguage = $("#DepartureDate").attr("data-lang");
        alert(currentLanguage);       
        $.preferCulture(currentLanguage);
```

No affect to the validators...

Comment: Possible duplicate of my own question :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756226/dot-separated-clientside-date-validation-in-asp-mvc-4/11771781#11771781

Comment: Thx, i saw your question. I dont use the bundle. It was a 1:1 upgrade from MVC3 to MVC4. I tried also to create a new MVC4 project from template and have the same problem. I removed then the bundling and this had also no impact.

Comment: Have you overridden the default jquery date validator as seen in the question?

Comment: No, everything is default. I can reproduce the bug in a new MVC4 project.

Comment: What about setting up your culture in web.config in system.web tag globalization for culture and uiCulture?

Comment: Sorry, no option. I have a combo box where the user can select 16 different languages, each might have it's own specific formatting. E.g. DE-de -> DD.MM.YYYY; en-en -> DD/MM/YYYY; en-us -> MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: "I set the UI culture of the current thread to german" - UICulture does not affect date formatting, have you tried setting CurrentCulture as well as CurrentUICulture?

Comment: You are right. I extend my question to complete this missing information.

Comment: There are issues with the jQuery date validation and different culture support so overridding the validator might be the only way. However, have you tried using the [DisplayFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring.aspx)?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388238/validate-a-date-in-a-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-3) you can use a web.config option to keep the client/server cultures in sync. Problem is client side validation will be determined by the client (browser) and server side is determined by the app so they are more than likely getting out of sync!

Comment: @James: Thx. I tried the web.config way, but we allow to switch languages (cultures) on the frontend. And yes, i saw the DisplayFormat Attribute, this doesnt help :-( It worked on MVC3, but was broken with MVc4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point is that Mvc3 doesnt validate at all dates on the client side that is the point. You just set the cultrure on the server side....but your culture settings are not reflected at all on the client side...at least the Mvc engine doesnt do it automatically. The only way to handle properly dates and numbers on the client side with cultures that differs from English is to use a a javascript globalization library that is able to parse properly dates in all cultures, and to set the client side culture equal to the server side culture, then you have to redefine properly all validation methods to use globalized functions.
Please read this post of my blog that clarifies how to handle properly globalization on the client side: http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2011/12/14/Globalization-Validation-and-DateNumber-Formats-in-AspNet-MVC.aspx

Moreover, please dont confuse CurrentCulture with CurrentUICulture CurrentUICulture doesnt affect at all the way numbers or dates are handled, but only the resource files containing culture specifi resources such as localized strings.

Finally, it is very unefficient to set the culture in the model binder, since the model binder is a recursive function so it si called hundreds of times during model reconstruction, and the culture setting operation is not a simple variable setting operation but it has a not negligible cost. It is better to write a global controller filter to handle culture setting (I always do this way) so the operation is performed just once per request

Comment: Thanks, will try this out tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try overwriting the default date validator:

```
// Replace dots so jq validator can understand what's going on
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod(
    "date",
    function (value, element) {
        var s = value;
        s = value.replace(/\./g, '/');

        // Chrome requires tolocaledatestring conversion, otherwise just use the slashed format
        var d = new Date();
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value))) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(s));
    },
    ""
    );
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
```

Comment: Thanks, Currently trying this out. I hope to find a solution without modifiying too much code. As said, it works with MVC3 without a problem.

Comment: I know and I'd really like to know what's the problem exactly, this clientside datepicker validation/formatting caused me so much headache it's unbelievable. This thing really should not be necessary.

Comment: I might consider this solution in combination with a custom model binder. I could format the date to Ansi Date format for all cultures and use the datetime overload where i can pass year, month and day seperately. But let's wait and see if there are better solutions :D

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the code with ILSpy it appears to be the newly introduced ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider that is adding the data-val-date attribute.

If you want to revert to MVC3 style functionality then simply removing that provider from the list of model validation providers does the trick.

It doesn't solve the problem but in a few lines of code may remove the problems caused by jquery validation's lack of globalization.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

...

protected void Application_Start()
{
  var providers = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers;
  var clientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider = providers.OfType<ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
  if ( clientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider != null )
  {
    providers.Remove( clientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider );
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft suggests to replace the new jquery.validate.js from mvc4 with the old jquery.validate.js from the MVC3 project template. This works, but the funny thing is, the bug is not in MVC4, it was in MVC3.

We use the way which was described by Francesco, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this only occurs in Chrome then it is due to the jquery version having a culture bug in the validation of dates.