# Display DateTime value in dd/mm/yyyy format in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, datetime-format

Is it possible to display a `DateTime` value in **dd/mm/yyyy** format with the help of `HTML Helper` methods in `Asp.NET MVC`? I tried to do this by using some formats in `@Html.LabelFor` and adding some annotations to the related property like below but it does not make any sense. Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.

**Model:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> RegistrationDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

After few hours of searching, I just solved this issue with a few lines of code

**Your model**

```
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the issued date.")]
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
```

**Razor Page**

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IssueDate)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueDate)
```

**Jquery DatePicker**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#IssueDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            currentText: 'Now',
            autoSize: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            showAnim: 'blind',
            highlightWeek: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Webconfig File**

```
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
    </system.web>
```

Now your text-box will accept **"dd/MM/yyyy"** format.

Comment: thanks mate, i was doing everything except the web.config thing but when i added your web.config line in mine, it worked perfect

Comment: I tryed all that you said, but it keeps failing in one point. I'm guessing that you don't have unobtrusive jquery activated, because if you have, it throws validation errors saying that the field is not a valid date, (try a date like 31/01/2014, bcb january 31.) Try it and tell me if you have same problem. Thnks

Comment: I just added the WebConfig section it's enough to get round it - MVC5 Helpers allow you to specify a Format for the date so visible display is not an issue - I was getting stuck with a hidden field that had an AU/GB date in it

Comment: tried but not working,Model was set, rebuild, script was included in create view, and the view was as(( @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.startDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } }))).... still in IE8 to IE 11 not working

Comment: This answer worked for me but dateFormat wasn't working, finally I realized I'm using Bootstrap datepicker and it's properties are different, [here](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) is details.

Answer (score 87):

All you have to do is apply the format you want in the html helper call, ie.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

You don't need to provide the date format in the model class.

Comment: And if you are concerned with the regional formatting you could try `{0:d}`

Comment: this will do noting, it's google chrome it self if you run the page in IE windows, you will not see date picker

Comment: It will be required to format on every page! Any global control will be appreciable!

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an older question, but for reference, a really simple way for formatting dates without any data annotations or any other settings is as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @Value = Model.StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") })
```

The above format can of course be changed to whatever.

Comment: How do you solve the submitted format when server is expecting datetime and you submit some formatted string ?

Comment: @David This save my entire week :)

Comment: @Muflix You need to set StartDate type as DateTime, mvc will automatically convert it into DateTime

Answer (score 10):

Since the question was "display" :

```
@Html.ValueFor(model => model.RegistrationDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Answer (score 7):

Or just use this in your View(Razor page)

```
@item.ResgistrationhaseDate.ToString(string.Format("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

I recommend that don't add date format in your model class

Comment: underrated solution

Answer (score 3):

You need to use html helper, and you don't need to provide date format in model class. e.x :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResgistrationhaseDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late to answer this in **2019**. but I tried all the answers and none worked for me. So I solved it simply this way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SellDateForInstallment, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
               new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" } })
```

`EditorFor` is what worked for me.

Note that `SellDateForInstallment` is a `Nullable` datetime object.

```
public DateTime? SellDateForInstallment { get; set; } // Model property
```

Answer (score 0):

I made  a global configuration in "Web.config" inside etiquet system web:

globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US

In CsHtml:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fechaConfirmacion, new { @type = "date", @Value = Model.fechaConfirmacion.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sszzz") })