# Remove time in controller's LINQ query with model that has a DateTime attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime, truncate

I have a ViewModel that displays my table

Model

```
public DateTime? startdate { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
var regions = from r in _odb.REGION_MSTR
              select new RegionModel
              {
                  regionid = r.REG_ID,
                  regionname = r.REG_NAME,
                  status = (r.INACTV_DT == null ? "Active" : "Inactive"),
                  startdate = r.STRT_DT
              };
```

View

```
<tbody id="dbBody">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            ...
            <td class="hidden">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startdate)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

This will display a `9/16/2016 12:00:00 AM`. How do I remove the `12:00:00 AM`? I tried using DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.STRT_DT), but still getting date with time.

Comment: Add a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]` attribute to the property

Comment: Yes, as per suggestion of @StephenMuecke just add property to `startdate`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You again! You never failed to answer all my questions :) It worked, thanks man!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you add this as an answer? So I can vote tag this as answered. Thank you!

Comment: Its already been marked as a dupe - answers can no longer be added (and there is enough info in that dupe to answer your question)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.startdate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Source: [Display DateTime value in dd/mm/yyyy format in Asp.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288675/display-datetime-value-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: OP is not wanting a textbox

Comment: `DisplayFor()` does not have an overload that accepts a format string :)

Comment: Just copy paste... :D

Comment: @REDEVI_, Pleae refer this: [Before you develop a solution, make sure you really understand the problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060323-00/?p=31803/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply@REDEVI_! Unfortunately, I'm looking for the string format inside a table

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller

```
    startDate = r.strt_DT.Date
```

Format to use

```
 StartDate = r.strt_DT.Date
```

try using like this

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.StartDate ) == r.strt_DT.Date
```

Comment: I tried this a earlier and had this error: `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: I am editing my answer please have a look