# DataFormatString for DateTime with mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

i have searched and tried to do it in many ways (changing the DataFormatString) but none of them are working. I'm also using datepicker for my Date fields.

```
 [Required]
 [Column(TypeName = "date")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yy}")]
 public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

and this is my view

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server_Cadworker.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Server_Cadworker.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server_Cadworker.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

any one has answer for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? You want to display date in some special way, or it just does not working at all?

Comment: it shows my date like "{0:MM.dd.yy}" and i want it to be like this {0:dd.MM.yy}

Comment: Are you using a jquery datepicker plugin (if so your `DataType` and `ApplyFormatInEditMode` are pointless. If you generating a HTML-5 datepicker (which is only supported in Chrome and Edge), then it needs to be `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` - ISO format, and the date is displayed in the users culture - that is the whole point of the control

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is good clarification. Actually, i am using HTML-5 datepicker that why i couldn't change it. I will try to use other datepicker. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To display date in dd.MM.yy just use:

```
myDate.ToString(dd.MM.yy);
```

There is no sutch thing as date format, you can just display it in different way :)
EDIT:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Date, new { @Value = Model.Date.ToString("dd.MMM.yy") })
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Date, "{0:dd.MM.yy}")
```

As a full list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Date.ToString("dd.MMM.yy")
        <hr />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: could you please more clarification, how can i use it and it should be in the view or in the model ?

Comment: all do you need can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288675/display-datetime-value-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-asp-net-mvc