# Datetime model cant be displayed on google chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-core, razor

I have datetime data type in my asp.net core mvc application it displays mm/dd/yyyy --:-- -- doest take input from datepicker . Readonly mode even displays this mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --  instead datetime passing to the model.what is solution there way to remove this data?

Comment: Post your code - both HTML/Javascript and server-side. What date picker did you use?  DateTime has no format, it's a binary value. Formats apply only when converting to text or parsing text. Even if you use a Javascript datepicker that returns dates as strings, ASP.NET Core will parse strings in the ISO8601 format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would guess that they are using `<input type="datetime" ...` from their statement "I have datetime data type" and the fact that it shows hyphens for the time portion; something that input type defaults to if not given an appropriately formatted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value format of datepicker is `yyyy-mm-dd` , if you set the displayFormat of DateTime type property , you should set the `type="text"` to the input , or you maybe get the error like `The specified value "02/12/1995" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".` Here is a example:

Model:

```
 public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; } 
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Age" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Birth" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Birth" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Birth" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        })
    });
</script>   
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: My problem only google chrome bring this mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --  even I made nullable datetime filed to remove this default value.

Comment: Thanks alot for all this Type="text" solution works for me.

Comment: Glad that my solution helps you, could you mark my reply as answer?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding from your question, you want to input date using `datepicker` and display the only date `mm/dd/yyyy` part instead of `mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --`.

You can achieve this by using data annotation with your model.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

And in your `razorview`, you can `Html helper` to input and show date.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

And for `readonly` show

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
```

Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288675/display-datetime-value-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-asp-net-mvc) for more understanding.

Answer (score -1):

As Kanavos commented above, formats only apply when converting to text or parsing text.

If you wish for individual pieces of your DateTime object to be shown and others to be hidden, you can do something like:

```
 var newFormat = dateTimeObj.ToString("<desired format>")
```

and replacing the "< desired format >" with one listed in the MS docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8