# Input datetime-local does not show value when loading page in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, input, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have an input in an asp.net mvc project, and the page receives values ​​through a model, however the value is not showing on the page.
When I click F12 and inspect the datetime-local element, the value is there, but not shown.
[image]

**The configure parameters datetime.**

> [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss}")]
> public DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }
> [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss}")]
> public DateTime DataUltimaAlteracao { get; set; }

**Div Dates**

```
<div class="grid-duas-colunas">
                <div class="form-group div-autor-1 col-4">
                    <label asp-for="DataPublicacao" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DataPublicacao" class="form-control" value="@Model.DataPublicacao"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DataPublicacao" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group div-autor-2 col-4">
                    <label asp-for="DataUltimaAlteracao" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DataUltimaAlteracao" class="form-control" value="@Model.DataUltimaAlteracao"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DataUltimaAlteracao" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Apparently, this formatting is not working correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display DateTime value in dd/mm/yyyy format in Asp.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288675/display-datetime-value-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: The solution that worked here was this: <input asp-for="DataUltimaAlteracao" class="form-control" value="@Model.DataUltimaAlteracao.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")" />