# Asp.net MVC set validation date format fails on Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with setting validations date format Chrome in asp.net mvc, for other browsers like IE,Firefox works correctly .

I have defined dates in my model like next code:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Data fi publicació")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime PublishingEndDate { get; set; }
```

And in my views :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PublishingEndDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishingEndDate)
```

The problem It seems that `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`, validates the date with format `MM/dd/yyyy`, but what I want is to validate with european format `dd/MM/yyyy`. How can I change default culture validations format date to `dd/MM/yyyy` ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I discover the problem only affects Chrome, with IE, Firexfox it works perfectly, it seems is a chrome bug, I found the solution in http://forums.asp.net/t/1729179.aspx/1

The validator method of jquery has to be override using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.calendarPicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

$.validator.addMethod('date',
    function (value, element, params) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }

        var ok = true;
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
        }
        catch (err) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    });
});
```

Comment: My problem was that if I picked a second date in the datepicker, it would give me a validation error - Only in Chrome (using 40.0.2214.115). This solution fixed it nearly three years after the original question! Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you've set your culture in web.config. This will use the appropriate date and number formatting for the culture chosen.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

```
$(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                todayBtn: true,
                language: "en-GB",
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                clearBtn: true,
                pickTime: false
            });

            $.validator.addMethod("date",
                function(value, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || parseDate(value, "dd-MM-yyyy") !== null;
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid client side validation, you don't want any data-val attributes associated with the input. So what I did is to write down the plain HTML instead of using TextFor or EditorFor etc...

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control">
```

Works fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use datetime picker:

Client validation issues can occur because of MVC bug (even in MVC 5) in *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js* which **does not accept date/datetime format in any way**. Unfortunately you have to solve it manually.

**My finally working solution:**

You have to include before:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.js")
```

You can install moment.js using:

```
Install-Package Moment.js
```

And then you can finally add fix for date format parser:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD.MM.YYYY", true).isValid();
    }
});
```