# MVC Custom Client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my mvc 3 application, I would like to execute a function when the user tries to submit the form.  Within that function I will check a number of fields to determine if the user has provided the necessary data before submission.

How can I hookup a script to be executed when the user tries to submit the form?

(within the custom validate function, I need to check if various checkboxes have been selected and if yes, then additional values are selected from dropdownlists etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I hookup a script to be executed when the user tries to submit the form?

You could subscribe to the `.submit` event of the form and after calling the standard client side validation call your custom function:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            // standard client validation failed => prevent submission
            return false;
        }

        // at this stage client validation has passed. Here you could call your
        // function and return true/false depending on the result of your
        // custom function
    });
});
```

Another possibility is to write custom validation attributes and hook up a custom adapter as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747466/29407) and a [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4784986/29407).

Comment: Dangit, beat me to it by 20 secs!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#formId').submit(function () {
    var standardIsValid = $(this).validate().form();
    var customIsValid = customValidations();
    if (!standardIsValid || !customIsValid) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view (RAZOR or ASPX), you will define a script like you would in html, and in there will be your client-side validation.

For example :

```
<script>
  //define your script here, ie. $.(#tagtovaildate).validate();
</script>

<html>
  //code
</html>
```