# web config values in mvc unobtrusive validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I store values in my web.config. These are settings for the website. For example the event min age limit is 16. I have created my own data annotations to do this and puull back the values using the configurationManager but now I want to create a client side version.

I have this at the moment in a ValidationExtender.js file.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkUserAgeOfEvent", function (value, element, param) {
    var dob = $("#DateOfBirth").val();

//do validation here
    if(ConvertToAge(dob) == minAge)
    {
        // do something
    }
    return true;
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("checkUserAgeOfEvent");
```

My problem is that how do I include my value from the web.config or do I have to hard code the min age value? I want to try and avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

> I have created my own data annotations to do this

If you implemented the `IClientValidatable` interface for your custom data annotation you could add custom values to the client as I have illustrated in the [`following post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4784986/29407).

Basically in your `GetClientValidationRules` method you would pass this `minAge` to the client:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
        ValidationType = "userage",
    };
    rule.ValidationParameters.Add("minAge", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinAge"]);
    yield return rule;
}
```

which could be easily retrieved on the client:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "checkUserAgeOfEvent", 
    function (value, element, params) {
        var dob = $("#DateOfBirth").val();
        var minAge = params.minAge;
        if(ConvertToAge(dob) == minAge) {
            // do something
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

Comment: Cool. I will check it out today.