# As in the validation range set its minimum value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, attributes, range

I have param "min_payed" in web.config.

And I have model

```
  public class Pay
    {
        [Required]
        [Range(10,99999999)]
        public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
    }
```

min value I need get from web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom range attribute that will read its min and max values from the `<appSettings>` section of the config file:

```
public class ConfigBasedRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public ConfigBasedRangeAttribute(): 
        base(GetConfigValue("min"), GetConfigValue("max"))
    {
    }

    private static int GetConfigValue(string key)
    {
        return int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]);
    }
}
```

and then decorate your model with it:

```
public class Pay
{
    [Required]
    [ConfigBasedRange]
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. You'll have to either implement IValidatableObject (and IClientValidatable for the clientside) or create your own dataannotation that checks the configuration file.

[Here's another post dealing with the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859880/stringlength-attribute-client-side-validation-and-a-membership-provider).