# What server validation logic transforms to unobtrusive client-side validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes, data-annotations

In MVC3 you could write something like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill some field that I need")]
public string someFieldThatINeed;
```

But what about custom validation attributes? Will they transforms to client-side javascript code and validate as well as embedded validation attributes do? Or do I need to write my own javascript client code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If custom attributes do not derive from some of the standard validation attributes or require some special validation logic you could implement the [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable.aspx) and write custom client adapters. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747184/perform-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute/4747466#4747466).