# Modify default ErrorMessage for StringLength validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, entity-framework-4

The default ErrorMessage for StringLength validation is a lot longer than I'd like:

> The field {Name} must be a string with a maximum length of {StringLength}.

I would like to change it universally to something like:

> Maximum length is {StringLength}.

I'd like to avoid redundantly specifying the ErrorMessage for every string I declare:

```
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage="Maximum length is 20")]
    public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage="Maximum length is 20")]
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
```

I'm pretty sure I remember there being a simple way to universally change the ErrorMessage but cannot recall it.

EDIT:

For the sake of clarification, I'm trying to universally change the default ErrorMessage so that I can input:

```
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
```

and have the error message say:

> Maximum length is 20.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can specify the StringLength attribute as follows on numerous properties

```
[StringLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
[StringLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
public string CellPhone { get; set; }
```

and add the string resource (named `StringLengthMessage`) in your resource file

```
"Maximum length is {1}"
```

Message is defined once and has a variable place holder should you change your mind regarding  the length to test against.

You can specify the following:

1. {0} - Name
2. {1} - Maximum Length
3. {2} - Minimum Length

**Update**

To minimize duplication even further you can subclass StringLengthAttribute:

```
public class MyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public MyStringLengthAttribute() : this(20)
    {
    }

    public MyStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
    {
        base.ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthMessage";
        base.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resource);
    }
}
```

Or you can override `FormatErrorMessage` if you want to add additional parameters. Now the properties look as follows:

```
[MyStringLength]
public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
[MyStringLength]
public string CellPhone { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to override the default, without having to have `ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]` for every user-inputted string in my schema?

Comment: No. But you can subclass StringLengthAttribute and specify the default values. See the update to my answer.

Comment: can I specify a StrengLength (i.e. `[MyStringLength(30)]`?

Comment: Yes, that will use the second constructor: `MyStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength)`

Comment: The top portion of your code works wonderfully (once I figured out how to make a resource file); however, the StringLengthAttribute override seems to only work on the server. I'm not receiving Client-side validation when using [MyStringLength] or [MyStringLength(30)].  Is there a way to have both server- and client-side validation for this override of StringLength?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747184/perform-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute/4747466#4747466

Comment: yes, that's just what I'm looking for.  A bit more complicated than I had hoped, but useful nonetheless.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @WernerStrydom: Just curious where you found what the string format placeholders are. I don't see it in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: I stepped into the source code of `StringLengthAttribute`. Look at the FormatErrorMessage method.

Comment: I've used the approach of this answer and it works for the maximumLength, but, what about named parameters? Here If I add the MinimumLength it is always considered 0.

Comment: Manually set the MinimumLength in the constructor as you see fit.

Comment: Should there not be a dot in the end of the message?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
[ StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length is {1}") ]
```

if I recall correctly that should be it.

Comment: And adding the error message to a resource file means it is only specified once.

Comment: @WernerStrydom, Please post an answer for how to specify it only once, as that is my question.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I reread your question later. But it looks like you got the full answer you were looking for now.

Comment: @Yarx: Where did you find the string format placeholder values? It isn't in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: I don't recall but upon looking into the source of the StringLengthAttribute, you can find the placeholder logic there.
{0} = Field Name, {1} = Max Length, {2} = Min Length