# C# MVC 3 Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If use default attribte, then validation work on server and browser

```
[StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StrLenMinMax", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

But if use custom attribute validation work only on server (validation on the page is only through an error by VIEW)

I am not have runtime validation, only after submit

```
[StringLengthEx(100, MinimumLength = 6)]
public string Password { get; set; }

public class StringLengthExAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
    {
        private const string StringLengthMin = "StrLenMin";
        private const string StringLengthMinMax = "StrLenMinMax";

        public StringLengthExAttribute(int maxLength):base(maxLength)
        {
            ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources);
            if (MinimumLength != 0)
            {
                MinimumLength = MinimumLength;
                ErrorMessageResourceName = StringLengthMinMax;
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessageResourceName = StringLengthMin;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is because client side validation (unObtrusive) translates the validator to JavaScript, and uses it in client side. Take a look into the page source.. If's it's a new attribute, - it doesn't know how to translate that to JS

Comment: this is not new attribute this polymorphism

Comment: @user3356386 Maybe you need to learn english better, but subclassing IS creating a new attibute. Whatever geenrates the javascript does not know the attbribute, so it can not generate javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a detailed answer to Your question [Perform client side validation for custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747184/perform-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute)

or you can just google for more https://www.google.lt/search?q=mvc+client+side+validation+custom+attribute&oq=mvc+client+side+validation+custom+attribute